How can jump code or go to definition with openvscode-server?
How can jump code or go to definition with openvscode-server, just like VS Code?
I try to go to definition with Ctrl and left mouse button in openvscode-server, but it not work.
For example, click left mouse button with Ctrl, I want jump code from "a[0] = 0" to "int a[10]",but it not work.
